# Can you add a circle shadow to a square p-checkbox from PrimeNG

Tags: html, css

When using the checkbox found on https://primefaces.org/primeng/checkbox. Is there a way to create a circle drop shadow behind it. I am trying to have a hover property that shows a large background circle like the radio button below. When using box-shadow it shows as square background shadow. Are there any approaches to add a circle similar to a box-shadow?

CSS on Hover:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px lighten(blue, 65%);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p-radioButton name="city" value="Chicago" [(ngModel)]="valRadio" id="city1"></p-radioButton>
    <label for="city1">Chicago</label>
</div>

<div>
    <p-checkbox name="group1" value="New York" [(ngModel)]="valCheck" id="city2"></p-checkbox>
    <label for="city2">New York</label>
</div>
```

Desired drop Shadow appearance:

[image]

Current drop Shadow appearance:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`blur-radius` is the third value `box-shadow` property.

This is the value you want to increase to get circle shadow.
You can test it in your browser but I would suggest to increase it to at least 10px:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 8px lighten(blue, 65%);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I appreciate the insight. When using the blur-radius property. I assume it blurs the edge while rounding it out. Do you know if there is a property that can be used to maintain a sharp round edge like the one shown in the first screenshot?

Comment: Do you mean to radius only shadow or make a checkbox circle also? If you mean shadow only, the property I mentioned above should do this for you. It will change to the circle if radius is equivalent of 50% in pixels. You probably need to test it on your browser mate